# Что происходит с исходным кодом в Docker образе?

Tags: c#, docker

Пример с официального сайта Microsoft, просто для примера

```
# https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /source

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY aspnetapp/*.csproj ./aspnetapp/
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY aspnetapp/. ./aspnetapp/
WORKDIR /source/aspnetapp
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o /app --no-restore

# final stage/image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

Как я понял Dockerfile описывает как побилдить образ.
Но что происходит с исходным кодом программы, после того как образ собран ? Он остается внутри образа вместе с собраным приложением или нет ? Не очень понятно

Comment: Удаления в скрипте я не вижу, наверное да, остаётся

Comment: @tym32167 нет, тут используется multistage сборка. Так что исходник останется в первом stage, а во втором, который будет протегирован (и опубликован) будет только собранный файл. https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/ https://habr.com/ru/articles/349802/

Comment: @AlexeyTen о, прикольно. Как говорится, век живи - век учись. Спасибо!

Comment: @AlexeyTen - Спасибо большое!